# Dynamics CRM 2015 not updating JavaScript file properly

Tags: firefox, dynamics-crm-2015, javascript-debugger

The problem:
After editing my JavaScript file in the CRM textediting program, the changes are not updated when I test it in CRM. I am making subtle changes to a drop-down, nothing that breaks anything.
I am using Firefox, and unable to test this in other browsers (at least for the time being).

What I did was:

1. Made subtle changes to my javaScript file in the texteditor in MS Dynamics CRM 2015.
2. Press Publish all adjustments.
3. Open a new window with CRM.
4. Go to a formula with the drop-down, open it and find that it has not been updated.
5. So I open the debugger (<kbd>F12</kbd>) and confirm this.
6. In the debugger I open the tool setting and check the box with "Deactivate cache (when tool is open)".
7. Hit <kbd>F5</kbd> test again and it works! VOILA!
8. However if I shut the whole thing down (the browser) and open it up again, then CRM still loads the old JavaScript file, until I go to the debugger and do the whole thing again.

This is not acceptable, since CRM are suppose to load the updated JavaScript file as default.
Any help or advice is appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is: Remember to clear the cache.

One good way to test it, is by opening a browser with private browsing.

Comment: Depending on your browser you can force reload (Ctrl + F5 for IE) (Ctrl + R for chrome)